# Does the KafkaListener stop "gracefully" on application shutdown, or why not?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have an application that consumes from one topic, re-orders the messages according to an internal version number (for reasons I don't want to discuss) and publishes them on another topic. Because I don't think I can do that with a Streams-app, I'm doing it with a @KafkaListener and a subsequent kafkaTemplate.sendDefault.

While the app is running everything works just fine. But when I shut the app down, I still publish all received messages, but it seems like the listener hasn't comitted the offsets yet. Hence, another still running instance of my app receives the message again and publishes it to the other topic a second time.

I already tried setting `spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode: RECORD` and decreased the `auto-commit-interval`, but it's still happening.

Anyone got ideas?
Or do I have to manually tamper with the ListenerContainer?

Comment: how are you shutting the app down?

Comment: It is started and stopped through a startup script, unix-style.

Comment: i may be misunderstanding the details, but every topic consumer will receive a topic message. so if you have multiple consumers who receive the message and publish it to the next topic, you should expect N consumers will publish to the second topic N times

Comment: does the script kill -9, i.e. force kill or shut down gracefully?

Comment: The script shuts down gracefully. The consumers are all in the same consumer_group, and the messages have a unique message_key, so each topic partition is only consumed by one consumer.

Comment: Kafka takes care that this doesn't happen. Otherwise it would happen all the time, not just when I shut one instance down.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a bug. We tested kafka in cloud dev environments and passed for the time being because we found it a little immature. Good luck, hopefully someone with more expertise can shed light or verify that it is a bug